# Unable to get Route::get method to work in Laravel using Wamp

Tags: php, laravel-4, wamp

New to laravel and PHP programming. I managed to install laravel with wamp in Windows 7 according to this tutorial: http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Laravel-Framework-in-Windows. I moved all the contents of the public folder into C:/wamp/www/laravel. So, I can see the Laravel logo when I go to localhost:81/laravel/

Then, I was following this tutorial online (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U_0gNBN7Q7I) and somehow I was unable to view the html page when I go to localhost:81/laravel/mycontroller

app/controllers/MyController.php

```
<?php

class MyController extends BaseController
{
    public function loadView()
    {
        return View::make('myview');
    }
}
```

app/views/myview.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1></h1>
    <p>It worked!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

app/routes.php

```
Route::get('mycontroller', array('uses'=>'MyController@loadView'));
```

However, if I change the word 'mycontroller' to a '/', I can see the html page when I go to localhost:81/laravel. Anyone have any idea what I have done wrong here?

```
Route::get('/', array('uses'=>'MyController@loadView'));
```

Error Message

```
Not Found

The requested URL /laravel/mycontroller was not found on this server.
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: @sgt - laravel/public folder which contains packages, index.php and some other files

Comment: You probably forgot to activate the mod_rewrite for apache

Comment: @RaphaëlMalié How and where can I do that?

Comment: Click on the wamp icone in your taskbar -> Apache -> Apache modules -> rewrite_module (you will probably need to scroll down in the list of modules to find it)

Comment: @RaphaëlMalié - It worked. Could you reply with an answer so I can choose your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably forgot to activate the rewrite module for Apache.

Click on the wamp icone in your taskbar -> Apache -> Apache modules -> rewrite_module (you will probably need to scroll down in the list of modules to find it)

**Or** you can activate it manually in your file C:\wamp\bin\apache\ApacheX.X.X\conf\httpd.conf. Uncomment this line:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Comment: Thanks Raphael. Another thing to add that I did is to change AllowOverride none to All in the httpd.conf file under the directory segment like below:<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>